# Rendering objects with normal maps

Tags: normal-map

I'm rendering sprites from a model, and want to use tangent normal maps while rendered.  My models are simple, single shaded, low poly models.  I want to render the animations I have set where the model is that blue color, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  It seems like it should be easy.  Seeing as how all the faces are untextured, it feels like I shouldn't even have to unwrap anything.

I'm extremely new to blender, if someone could guide me step by step that'd be great.  The other questions I've seen on this involve baking and applying textures to simpler objects, but I'm just trying to render my original model with that blue color, as this is how you apply normal maps to sprites in Unity.

I previously was able to use the normal pass and then just adjust the colors using math in the node editor which made it extremely simple to render, but it seems this is rendered in camera space, as opposed to tangent space.  I need tangent space normal maps.  Anybody?

Comment: I think you should start on youtube and see a few tutorials on basic modeling and getting used to the interface. I don't think you are did try to avoid all of the technical terms on purpose but I do get a feeling that you probably have something that is complicated without a purpose.

Comment: If you don't want to remove the question should you make the question more on point and change the name on it. It will probably get a lot of downvotes from people that expect something else.

Comment: that response is not helpful.  whether you like the terms i'm using or not, i'm pretty sure you understand that i'm trying to convey that i want my model to be renderable to look like this.  https://stringhamd.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/suzanne_render.jpg?w=300&h=151

Comment: seems answer was just to download the normal map blue as an image, and apply it as a shadeless texture material,.  then use this to produce the sprites normal maps during render.  i'm still not sure if this produces tangent space maps.  i get different results than when i use the normal pass, which supposedly just uses camera space.  still looking for more incite.  the colors appear slightly washed out as compared to the normal space maps produced by passing it to the node editor.